# The specified Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.7' was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

cannot start .NET Core app because of this error:

"*It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.7' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0.7'.
The program '[1560] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).*"

Editing .csproj didn't help. It looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.7</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a (longer) while, eventually it turned out that the solution is to comment out RuntimeFrameworkVersion in .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<!--<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.7</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>-->
<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

It is worth mentioning that the problem occured after my collegues upgraded a .NET Core to higher version and I did 'Get latest version'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the right .NET Core runtime installed. It's not good enough that's a .NET Core 2 runtime; it needs to be a minor version that is equal to or encompasses the version you're trying to target. You can see all the available runtimes here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all. Specifically, you need 2.0 Runtime (v2.0.7) or higher. You can just choose 2.1, though. 2.0.7 will be rolled in and then, if you do end up upgrading your project later, you won't run into this issue again.

Comment: Unfortunately, to my surprise installing 2.0.7 didn't help. After clean solution, rebuild, restart of comp I'm getting the very same error

Comment: Are you just running the app or trying to work on it in Visual Studio? For the latter, you'll need the full SDK, not just the runtime.

Comment: Chris, thanks for a quick reply. I need to debug it in VS, so SDK has to be added. However, after I ensured that I have SDK 2.1.200 the error remains there.